# why PHP shows created session token differently in some pages?

Tags: token, php

I've used the code below to create a token in my project.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
?>
```

and send this token to other pages using a hidden input or as a query string.
But in some target pages, created session token is not as same as sent value from the previous page. Sometimes I saw this when I run the project in **IE**, or sometimes when I work with `$_GET` to fetch sent value.
What is this problem for ? And how can I solve it ?

Comment: There's no need to pass this through anything. Once you create the session, you've got it stored in the session. Also, are you creating this at the top of every page?

Comment: As solutions for CSRF attacks, I have to send this value in the way I have mentioned. Yes, I create it at top of index.php that is my main file.

Comment: So you're creating a new one for every single request?

Comment: I create a new token on top of UI pages (index.php), and send it to processing files. There, I will compare the sent value with token session value.

Comment: By the sounds of it, you're overwriting the token upon page reload. When somebody submits a form and you do a CSRF check, you've already overwritten the session token.

Comment: No I don't. New token will be created when user come back to UI. The problem occurs on processing file. By the way, I said it happens only sometimes and in some situations. Not always ...

Comment: Well chances are, you're regenerating the token sometimes, before you've had a chance to compare. That's the only real option.

Comment: But I have token session creation code only once in my code. Also, imagine that it works well in Chrome, but when I want to do compare in IE, it stops working

Comment: The only connection between sessions and the browser, is the cookie that contains the session id, if you have that feature enabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48772/discussion-between-mohammad-bagher-saberi-and-ollieread)